# DataTables read array inside object

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

my question is simple: how can I read an array inside object with datatables?

**object**

I want to read the array "data" :

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "4",
      "tienda_id": "5",
      "tienda_nombre": "sad",
      "total": 123,
      "logo": null,
      "fecha": "2017-04-02T23:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

**datatable**:

```
        var x.DataTable({
            "ajax" : myAjaxUrl,
            "columns": [{
                "data": "data.fecha" // this doesn't work
            }, {
                "data": "data.total"  // this doesn't work
            }, {
                "data": "data.logo"  // this doesn't work
            }],
              //..............
        });
```

Thank you @Sotjin I know how to read a json that's not the problem, the problem is in the columns data:

```
       "columns": [{
            "data": "data.fecha" // this doesn't work
        }, {
            "data": "data.total"  // this doesn't work
        }, {
            "data": "data.logo"  // this doesn't work
        }],
```

The ajax of the datatable returns the object then in columns iterate that object and show the data in the datatable `"data": "data.fecha" // this doesn't work`

for example:

```
 {
 "data": [
        {
          "id": "4",
          "tienda_id": "5",
          "tienda_nombre": "sad",
          "total": 123,
          "logo": null,
          "fecha": "2017-04-02T23:00:00.000Z"
        }]
}
//...
 "columns": [{
                "data": "data.fecha"
            }, {
                "data": "data.total" 
            }, {
                "data": "data.logo" 
            }],
```

This works

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "4",
      "tienda_id": "5",
      "tienda_nombre": "sad",
      "total": 123,
      "logo": null,
      "fecha": "2017-04-02T23:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

This dont works

Answer (score 0):

```
 var json = {
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "4",
      "tienda_id": "5",
      "tienda_nombre": "sad",
      "total": 123,
      "logo": null,
      "fecha": "2017-04-02T23:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

To read `data` property:

```
json.data[0].fecha
json.data[0].logo
...
```

If you have multiple object in `data`, you can run loop to do some action with each of them:

```
json.data.forEach(function(obj) {
   console.log(obj);
});
```

Comment: @JoseLuis i did some edit too, `json.data[0].fecha` is what you need if you have only one object in `json.data` always

Comment: Yes but i have not 1 object only, i just showed 1 in the example

Comment: @JoseLuis is that what you need? (edit), you want those 3 elements from multiple objects?

Comment: No bacause I use ajax method of DataTables if I use your example I have to create another ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below:

```js
var x.DataTable({
   "ajax" : myAjaxUrl,
   "columns": [
      { "data": "fecha" }, 
      { "data": "total" }, 
      { "data": "logo" }
   ],
   // ...
});
```

See [Ajax sourced data](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax#Data-array-location) for more information.